Optimal estimate under altered MSE loss function
Suppose I am interested in estimating $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ and I observe a noisy data point $\tilde{\theta}=\theta + N(0,\sigma^2)$ where $\sigma^2$ is known. I am interested in constructing an estimator $m(\tilde\theta)$ to optimize the custom risk function
$m^{*} = \arg \min_{m} \mathbb{E}[m(\tilde\theta) - \theta]^2 + k \times \mathrm{Var}[m(\tilde\theta)] $
where $k \ge 0$ is a parameter which increases the intolerance for estimator variance above the standard MSE risk.
When $k=0$ the estimator is $m^{*}=\tilde\theta$. When $k>0$ what is the optimal estimator?

Hi: Just for clarity, I would change the $\hat{\theta}$ to $\tilde{\theta}$ because the hat usually denotes an estimator which makes things confusing.

Your $\arg \min$ statement probably doesn't mean what you want it to.  Based on your first line, $\mathbb{E}[\hat{\theta}-\theta]^2 =\sigma^2$ regardless of what $m$ is.  Assuming that "$m$" really means "$m(\hat{\theta})$", all you have is the last term on the right hand side, and the simplest way to minimize $k\mathrm{Var}[m(\hat{\theta})]$ is to set $m(\hat{\theta})$ equal to a constant, any constant, as its variance will then be zero.

Thanks for the comments, fixed those issues. Should read more coherently now?

Yes, much clearer, thanks!
